# Get zipcode from google api?

Tags: google-maps

how to get zipcode from google api ? i got lat.,long.,but i want to get zipcode

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?

Answer (score 9):

You can call this api:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.383253,-122.078075&sensor=false

full documentation here: [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests)

Comment: just add &key=API_KEY at the end

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/f73f736c4e024e7b

Answer (score 0):

Just query the [geocode API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) with the following string "zip XXXXX" and if you have a valid zip, they will send you back the lat/lon and more. You'll need to check the **Placemark.AddressDetails.Country.AdministrativeArea.Locality.PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber** field of the response to make sure you got a good match for the zip.